# multi-root-workspace command with folder param

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have found only the action -> 'workbench.action.addRootFolder' which opens dlg and doesn't accept params.
Is there a vscode command for 'add folder' which accept param (folder path)?

Answer (score 0):

vscode.workspace.updateWorkspaceFolders(workspace.workspaceFolders ? workspace.workspaceFolders.length : 0, null, { uri: ...});

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api